# Encryption of Hard-Drive or Folder

Tags: encryption

I have a question, is it possible to bind an encrypted folder/harddrive to a specific PC?
Like I have the encryption-password, but I couldn't take out the hard-drive and decrypt on another PC?

Regards,

Comment: Store the key in the TPM.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen any sowftware like that. Also commercial solutions, normally alows you to mount the encrypted HD on a different device and decrypt it using the right passphrase.
Are you sure you really need such scenario? 
My work laptop for innstance has the full HD encrypted, and when the laptop died I was able to plut the HD on a new laptop and access out of the box al my data.